# map function and asynchronous function calls in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I did my best to mock my use case :

```js
function SubComponent({project}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/api/projects${project.projectId}`).then(res=> setState(res.data))
  },[])

  return (<div>
    {state}
  </div>)
}

function MainComponent({projects}) {
  return (
    projects.map(project => (
      <SubComponent project={project}></SubComponent>
    ))
  )
}
```

I pass the project prop to my sub component, the sub component then makes an axios call. Will the main component wait or will it just continue looping causing it to render false data on sub component.